Can a Catboost oblivious tree split on the same feature more than once
When training an oblivious decision tree in Catboost, can it use the same feature more than once for splitting? Let's say there is a feature age.
If the first split happens on age>30, the data gets divided into two non-overlapping sections. Any further splits on that feature (say age>50), will have no samples in it for the first split where age<30.
Given that Catboost uses decision tables, some of the entries in there would not be filled and the algorithm couldn't predict anything for those regions.
On the other hand, if a feature can be used only once, this automatically limits the depth to the number of features.
Is this understanding correct and which option does Catboost use?
